# Find complex roots from a nonlinear equation

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica

I need to find the roots from the equations as follows (Mathematica):

```
Sqrt[3]/2*x-(I-x*Sqrt[3]/2*c^2)*I/Sqrt[2*Pi]/d^3*Integrate[t*Exp[-t^2/2/d^2]/(Sqrt[3]/2*x+I*(t+b0)),{t,-Inf,Inf}]=0
```

i.e. as the picture shows:

[image]

where *c*, *d*, and *b*<sub>0</sub> is given parameters, *x* is a complex root needs to find.
I have tried several methods, including scanning the real and imagine part of *x* and the iteration approach, but non of them could resolve all the cases.

Are there any general approaches that could solve such kind of equation efficiently, or by MATLAB/Mathematica?

Comment: Maybe differentiate it and use odesolve?

Comment: Actually, command fsolve in MATLAB can solve some cases for b0 > 0, but failed at b0 < -1.

Comment: You have syntax errors (i->I, pi->Pi); once you fix them the integral can be done analytically and you can use `FindRoot` to solve the equation.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. However, does anyone know the general approaches besides the FindRoot or fsolve?

Comment: The integration looks doable analytically from a first look. Checking that now...

Comment: Well, it is doable analytically, but will get you an imaginary error function in the end... not quite handy, although it has only a single zero.

Comment: @Tony check `FindRoot` in Mathematica. And consider posting this in mathematica.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

did you try Matlab's mupad? it is a powerful symbolic tool, very similar to Maple wich gives really good results in non-numerical mathematics. Try there. declare the equation, give assumptions to the software ,i.e `assume c real positive` (don't copy this, I dont remember the proper syntax) and then `solve`! It will very likely find a solution if it exits (sometimes in some mathematical cases that you even don't know!)

Comment: Thanks Ander, I will check mupad.

Comment: Hi, Ander! Since I am a little bit unfamiliar with mupad, I am stilling learning. But I have performed the same way in Mathematica, and it works!